# Cubic Directed Cayley graphs of 2-generated torsion-free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a torsion-free group $G=\langle x,y \rangle$ such that the directed Cayley graph $\Gamma=Cay(G,\{x,y,x^{-1}y\})$ contains a finite cubic induced subgraph? The vertex set of $\Gamma$ is $G$ and there is an arc from $a$ to $b$ (for two elements $a,b\in G$) if $ab^{-1}\in\{x,y,x^{-1}y\}$. An obvious necessary condition is that $G$ must be non-cyclic. By cubic I mean the number of vertices which are adjacent to a vertex is $3$.

The motivation is that if such group $G$ exists then one can construct a counterexample for Kaplansky's Zero divisor conjecture over $G$.

Comment: By cubic, do you mean of out-valency three? (Saying "are adjacent" is a bit unclear when dealing with an asymmetric relation.)

Comment: @verret : Two vertices $u$ and $v$ "are adjacent" if there is an arc from $u$ to $v$ or there is an arc from $v$ to $u$.

Comment: Can you explain how is it possible that the number of vertices adjacent to a vertex is 3? The vertices adjacent to $g\in G$ are $xg, x^{-1}g, yg, y^{-1}g$. The only way $g$ can have 3 neighbours is if $x=y$ or $x=y^{-1}$ and then in fact $g$ already has only two neighbours and $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: @EhudMeir : The graph is directed.

Comment: How does that solve the issue?
There are directed edges from g to xg, x^{-1}g, yg and y^{-1}g.

Comment: @EhudMeir : Why there is an arc from $g$ to $x^{-1}g$?

Comment: Okay, I just now see my mistake, sorry about that. I thought that the set was $\{x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}\}$, and not $\{x,y,x^{-1}y\}$. In this case I have another question: you mean that you have 3 edges in total, both inbound and outbound? Since the group $G$ acts transitively on the set of vertices of the graph, it will be true for one vertex if it is true for all of them.

Comment: @EhudMeir : Yes I mean that we have 3 edges in total, both inbound and outbound.